# Images in the project NOT adding to array - don't know why

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, image, nsmutablearray

I have to sets of images. Each set has 16 images. One set is called 0.png through to 15.png the other is a0.png through to a15.png.

In my app, it loads each one dependent on a variable (which by logging, I have proved it works)

here is the code

```
[MemoryManager sharedMemoryManager];

NSLog(@"THEME: %@", [MemoryManager sharedMemoryManager].themeName);
    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if([MemoryManager sharedMemoryManager].themeName == @"hand"){
    NSLog(@"Here 2");


[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"]]; //
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];//1
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];//2
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];//3
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"]];//4
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"]];//5
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]];//6
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"]];//7
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"]];//8
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]];//9
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"]];//10
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"]];//11
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"]];//12
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"]];//13
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"14.png"]];//14
[imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"15.png"]];//15

}
if([MemoryManager sharedMemoryManager].themeName == @"letters"){
    NSLog(@"Here 3");


    //[imageArray removeAllObjects];
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a0.png"]]; //
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a1.png"]];//1
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a2.png"]];//2
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a3.png"]];//3
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a4.png"]];//4
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a5.png"]];//5
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a6.png"]];//6
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a7.png"]];//7
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a8.png"]];//8
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a9.png"]];//9
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a10.png"]];//10
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a11.png"]];//11
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a12.png"]];//12
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a13.png"]];//13
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a14.png"]];//14
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a15.png"]];//15


    NSLog(@"Here 4");
}
```

The log says

```
2010-05-26 21:30:57.092 Memory[22155:207] Here 1
2010-05-26 21:30:57.093 Memory[22155:207] THEME: letters
2010-05-26 21:30:57.095 Memory[22155:207] Here 3
2010-05-26 21:30:57.109 Memory[22155:207] Here 4
```

The images are in the same folder the .xproj file is. They simply is just not working.
Any ideas? 
Cheers

Comment: What exactly is not working? The log shows it's getting through your code...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? "Not working"?? What is not working?

Comment: the 0-15 images are going in instead of the a0-a15 images. So the wrong ones show up later in the app! 
No idea why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. Long story short, I had forgot to add the if statements to another part of the code that happened during gameplay - thus it looked like it was not loading the images correctly, however the code was working just fine.

Ah one day.. xcode will be able to tell you what you are doing wrong sooner! i wish..